# What are the missable equipment/items in Bravely Default?

Tags: bravely-default

What are the missable equipment by events? (such as changes in landscape; changes in area accessibility (if any))

What are the missable equipment/items in boss fights? (Those that can only be gotten from stealing)

I need the thief job and its related job skills to make stealing efficient, but I don't want to use the thief job all the time. Which boss fights contain missable equipment so I know when to change class to thief?

Comment: Pretty much all the boss fights have a save point just before them.  Save at the save point, set thief as your job (or secondary), go into the fight and steal.  See what you steal and decide if you want to keep the item or if it's not worth it and reload from the save...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/729328-bravely-default/faqs/68431) that lists all limited availability items at the bottom, it looks like **there are actually no missable boss items that you can steal**.

All limited items that you are able to steal from bosses are also available in chests or in the area.